# Emacs separate init file for no-window mode

Tags: emacs

I have my color theme settings and a function to automatically maximize emacs on startup in my .emacs file, however, using this .emacs file with no window mode `-nw` results in an error since an X window is not initialized. So I was wondering if it was possible to use a separate init file or check in the original .emacs file to see if emacs is started in no window mode, and then call the maximize and set color theme commands accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `window-system` is not recommended for this, ever since `graphic-display-p` was added to Emacs (way back in Emacs 22).  Do not use `(if window-system...)`.  Use this instead:

```
 (if (display-graphic-p) ...)
```

If you use your init file with both an old Emacs version (prior to Emacs 22) and a new one, then use this:

```
 (if (if (fboundp 'display-graphic-p) (display-graphic-p) window-system) ...)
```

Comment: Alright, I will use that instead, but what is the difference between display-graphic-p and window-system?

Comment: I can't give you a good answer to that, sorry.

Comment: This answer of @Lindydancer shows the docs of display-graphic-p and window-system and when the use of window-system is not recomended https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/8200

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the X specific part into

```
(if window-system ...)
```